# Mailinabox adding TOTP two-factor authentication to admin panel login

Tags: javascript, email, admin, two-factor-authentication

I am trying to add 2FA to mailinabox admin panel login. I am following their [documentation](https://mailinabox.email/guide.html#admin) but I can't find where that section is explained. From their project repo, I can see a [PR](https://github.com/mail-in-a-box/mailinabox/pull/1814) that was merged to implement 2FA.

Someone, please point me to a tutorial or resource that I can use to implement the 2FA to admin panel login on mailinabox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just reached out to mailinabox and their response is they will release a version with 2FA in the next 10 days. [Link to the discussion](https://discourse.mailinabox.email/t/implement-2fa-on-admin-panel-on-existing-mailinabox-setup/7181)